# AAS Congruence Included Side?

Tags: geometry, congruences-geometry

When proving congruence between two triangles, AAS is a common method. However, like that for SAS the angle must be included, is there any restriction on where the side must be for AAS to work? For example, does it need to be included in the angles?

Comment: The name "AAS" tells you the side is not included. If the side is to be included between the angles, we would use "ASA".

Comment: If you know two angles, you know all three.

Answer (score 0):

Since AA implies AAA (sum of angles in a triangle equals a straight angle $= 180$ degrees), it doesn't matter whether the side is included or not.  The congruence method works either way.

Comment: Provided the correspondences are maintained, of course.